# Nested Field, Arrays and hierarchical structure in Big Query Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Table preview: all fields are nullable strings

[image: table schema]

structure is already ordered hierarchically:

e.g. urls 1111112 and 1111113 are "brothers" to each other and "children" of url 1111116

I would like to have for each element of **modemio_url_id** an array with all **brother urls** and **children**

for getting all **children** I tried something like this

```
SELECT
  url5_id as url_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT url6_id IGNORE NULLS) children
FROM  `xxx.modemio_url_schema`
GROUP BY url5_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
  url4_id as url_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT url5_id IGNORE NULLS) children
FROM `xxx.modemio_url_schema`
UNION ALL 
[...]
GROUP BY url4_id 
HAVING url_id is not null
```

Any suggestion on how to find **brothers** or a better way to get **children**?

**expected outcome**

[image: outcome table]

Comment: you should provide example of expected output that matches input you presented

Comment: hi Mikhail, any suggestion on how to achieve this? should I go for a multi step approach?